# Installing MS Office when all "allowed licences" have been used

Tags: installation, microsoft-office, license

My wife's laptop died recently (*sniff*)
I tried to install our copy of Office 2003 on a replacement, but got a "Maximum number of licences have been used" type message stating it was installed on 3 computers.

Considering one of those computers has gone the way of the Dodo, is there any way to reclaim that license and install office on the replacement PC?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The activiation wizard should give you an [Activate by Telephone](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950929) option.  Select that, and explain to the MS representative what has happened.

Comment: +1: Excellent I'll try again, and keep and eye out for that, thanks mate :)

Comment: PS, if this is a single retail license of Office, then I think you meant to say that *your* laptop died, not your wife's.  http://news.office-watch.com/t/n.aspx?articleid=734&zoneid=13

Comment: Most of the Office Home and Student editions are licensed for three PCs.